# button multi-line bootstrap with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a bootstrap button with multi-line text and inserting variables on each line.  This illustrate what I mean:

[image]

I'm trying to add in the variables so they appear as shown.  I've created a multi-line string variable and tried to add it via jquery:

```
button.text(textVariable)
```

but the text doesn't wrap in the button. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please show what you mean by a “multi-line string variable.”